Extract Hebrew text from PDF in React
I was looking all across the web and also digging StackOverflow to find a solution, but couldn't find anything that works. I need to extract Hebrew text from PDF file, when trying to extract English text, it works fine, but when trying to extract from Hebrew I get gibberish text. Even when adding encoding to it does not work.
I have tried react-pdf, pdf.js and all other libraries.
This is the code of using pdf.js:
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.min.mjs';
await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.mjs');

export async function getDocumentText(filePath: string, fileUrl: string) {
  const path = filePath ? filePath : fileUrl;
  const pdf = await pdfjs.getDocument(path).promise;
  const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
  const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
  console.log(`TextContent extracted from PDF: ${textContent}`);
}

Got this error: TypeError: Promise.withResolvers is not a function
And I was implementing it using this answer
Also tried this code:
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
import pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjsLib.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

export async function getDocumentText(filePath: string | undefined, fileUrl: string | undefined) {
  const path = filePath ? filePath : fileUrl;
  console.log(`[PaycheckDataExtractor]: Path: ${path}`);
  const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ url: path, verbosity: 0 }).promise.then(function (pdf) {
    console.log(`[PaycheckDataExtractor]: PDF: ${pdf}`);
  });
  console.log(`[PaycheckDataExtractor]: PDF: ${pdf}`);
  const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
  console.log(`[PaycheckDataExtractor]: Page: ${page}`);
  const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
  console.log(`[PaycheckDataExtractor]: Text content: ${textContent}`);
}

And it did not crash or anything, but does not do nothing and the last log is the [PaycheckDataExtractor]: Path:
The project is written in TypeScript on React Next.js latest version.
Does someone have a solution?

Promise.withResolvers is a fairly recent feature. What environment and version are you trying to run it in (browser/Node/other)?
